# Taking more time to upload image on rackspace

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, paperclip

I have an application where i am uploading an image using paperclip and paperclip-cloudfiles gems to upload image on rackspace.
This functionality takes about minute to upload image on rackspace through localhost.
And on heroku gives an application error.

code is build up by using following guidelines.
http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/04/16/using-rackspace-cloudfiles-with-paperclip/

got following error on heroku

```
2013-03-22T14:49:02+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path=/en/people/dC95vKJ7mr4OadeJe5kdxp/update_avatar host=foodswap.herokuapp.com fwd="14.97.68.176" dyno=web.1 queue=0ms wait=0ms connect=1ms service=30950ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-03-22T14:49:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Disconnected from ActiveRecord
2013-03-22T14:49:02+00:00 app[web.1]: reaped # worker=0
2013-03-22T14:49:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to ActiveRecord
2013-03-22T14:49:03+00:00 app[web.1]: worker=0 ready
```

Using:
ruby 1.9.3
rails 3.0.19
paperclip 3.4.1
paperclip-cloudfiles 2.3.8.3

So how i can reduce time for image processing or extend server time?
or delayed job will help me out to upload image?how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku times out requests that take longer that 30seconds - which is always a problem with uploads.

Using Amazon S3 you can direct upload without going through Heroku and have it pass a response to Heroku once the upload has completed thereby entirely bypassing Heroku's timeout - you would need to look to see if Rackspace offer such functionality.